# Inserting Google Map in Lightbox after using .load()

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

So I am making this website for a final project (highschool) and I am using

```
    <script>
        function carregaPagina($link){
            $( "#destaques" ).load( $link );
            }
    </script>
```

to load the pages into a div, so that everytime you click a link on the menu it doesn't refresh the entire page.HTML looks like this:

```
    <li>
       <a href="#" onClick="carregaPagina('contactos.php');">CONTACTOS</a>
    </li>
```

(just an example).

Now I want to insert a google map on the contacts page, inside a lightbox, so it shows the address and the user can click to see the map if they wish to do so.
I've used [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map) to get the map. I've tried to put it just inside the contacts page like this

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
         <head>
         <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
         <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
         <script>
             function initialize() {
                   var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
                   var mapOptions = {
                   center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
                   zoom: 8,
                   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                   }
                var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
                }
             google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
  </html>
```

which works if I load the page [alone](http://i765.photobucket.com/albums/xx298/MMF18/Sem%20Tiacutetulo_zps0hjirsm4.png) but not if I load it using the code , or if I put it inside of a lightbox, like this:

```
<body>
    <p>This is the main content. To display a lightbox click <a href =   "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">here</a></p>
<div id="light" class="white_content"><div id="map-canvas"></div> <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
<div id="fade" class="black_overlay"></div>
</body>
```

I got the lightbox somewhere in Stackoverflow.
Can anyone please help me?

P.S: Sorry for my english. As you may have noticed by looking at my code, it isn't my native language

Comment: You can check the website @ www.cdq.pt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using load, why not use iframe inside the lightbox instead where it will load a page that contains a full width map

Sample:

```
<div id="light" class="white_content"> 
<iframe height="300" width="300" src="map_page.php"></iframe>
 <a href = "javascript:void(0)" onclick = "document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
```